# Opening files in LibreOffice logs out and returns to the login screen

Tags: libreoffice, login-screen, gdm

I was working with some .pptx presentations, and when I opened a new .pptx file, a tty appeared and the system reloaded back to the Ubuntu login screen.

Since then, every time I open LibreOffice Impress, the same thing happens. 
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you post the output of `/var/log/?dm.log` (? = gdm, kdm, ...), `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `~/.xsession-errors` on http://paste.ubuntu.com/?

Comment: Could be this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/778490)

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the logs, to see if you can get the problem. Also, this seems like a bug, and Askubuntu is not the best place to solve it. You can find all the possible ways of asking for a solution [here](http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/).
I personally recommend you the IRC Channel or the mailing list.